# Error with installing app on android device by AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

[image]
This is the problem that android studio show me when I try to install the app on my device (Asus zenfone).The app is unistalled by far, and I don't know how to solve It, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't worry go to following process this error will be gone...

go to File >> Settings >> search "instant run" >> if checked then unchecked it >> apply >> ok.

problem solve

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry. Your app may have saved something to your phone (like temp files or even shared preferences) and, facing a new version (usually a signed one) it alerts you that data can be deleted. Just a security warning. In your case, no need to worry unless you want to preserve previous data. As you said app is already uninstalled, then your info is disposable too, right? Then just ignore (click OK). If you would want to preserve previous data, then it would be another scenario. Best.

Comment: Ok, then your opinion is check the residue files and delete them? But the problem is that android studio still don't install the app

Comment: When similar occurs with me I just press OK and the new install happens... sorry. Ciao Italia.